# Python splitting string index out of range

Tags: python, html-parsing

I am trying to split the following a tag:

```
<h3><a href="#AC Adapter" onclick="getProductsBasedOnCategoryID('Asus','AC Adapter','ET1611PUT','6941', this, 'E Series')">AC Adapter

            </a></h3>
```

Using the following code:

```
print "FETCHING CATEGORY"
    atag = s.h3
    for data in atag:
        while getattr(atag, 'name', None) != 'h3':
            atag = atag.nextSibling
        atag.a
        atag = literal_eval('(' + atag.nextSibling.replace(', this', '').split('(', 1)[1])
        print atag
```

However, i get the following error:

```
File "//CPSBS/RedirectedFolders/aysha/My Documents/asus_tables(edited) a tags.py", line 84, in <module>
    atag = literal_eval('(' + atag.nextSibling.replace(', this', '').split('(', 1)[1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I am guessing there is something wrong i am doing? Also this `a` tag has an `onclick` attribute i would like to access instead so how would i input that into the following code?

Here is the url i am parsing the data from

http://www.asusparts.eu/partfinder/Asus/All In One/E Series

**[EDIT]**

Navigational Tree i am trying to retrieve the data from

```
<div id="accordion" class="ui-accordion ui-widget ui-helper-reset ui-accordion-icons" style="width: 760px;" role="tablist"> 
    <h3 class="ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-active ui-corner-top" role="tab" aria-expanded="true" aria-selected="true" tabindex="0"> 
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span> 
        <a onclick="getProductsBasedOnCategoryID('Asus','AC Adapter','ET10B','6941', this, 'E Series')" href="#AC Adapter" tabindex="-1" loaded="Loaded">AC Adapter </a> 
    </h3> 
    <div id="6941" class="ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-accordion-content-active" role="tabpanel" style="display: block;"> 
        <table class="productTableList"> 
            <tbody> 
        </table> 
        <table class="productTableList"> 
            <tbody> 
                <tr style="height:90px;background-color:#ebf4ff;"> 
                    <td class="ProduktLista" width="70px"> 
                    <td class="ProduktLista" width="315"> 
                        <a onclick="getProductInformationModal("Asus","14G110008340");"> 
                        <br>
```

Comment: Instead of us showing the errors because we probably can run the code, why don't you break that eval into multiple individual lines, check what is being returned from the ``split``. It probably will be helpful if you try that first. or at least post what you got after doing that.

Answer (score 1):

When you're faced with these types of problems, and you can't immediately see what the problem is, then you need to divide up the complex expression. Instead of:

```
atag = literal_eval('(' + atag.nextSibling.replace(', this', '').split('(', 1)[1])
```

rewrite it to (you should, of course, use variable names that make more sense):

```
nextSibling = atag.nextSibling
txt1 = nextSibling.replace(', this', '')
split = txt1.split('(', 1)
txt2 = split[1]
txt3 = '(' + txt2
atag = literal_eval(txt3)
```

This will get you the exact expression where the problem exist, and a print statement of the values involved should give you the answer..

Comment: it doesnt print anything out :/ i edited my post above and added a snippet of the navigational tree of the html